# Attribute Error while using Image Module from PIL library in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library, attributeerror

I am building a simple python 3 program to open and resize an image. I am using Pycharm. I imported Image from PIL and tried to run the following command:

```
image1 = Image.open('<file location>')
```

but the interpreter is showing an Attribute Error that type Image has no attribute open.

My program is:

```
from PIL import Image
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

image2 = Image.open('hp png.png')

hp_image2 = Label(root , image = image2)

hp_image2.pack(fill = BOTH)

root.mainloop()
```

and the output is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hh9oX.png)

Comment: Include the output as text, not a link to an image

Comment: Please add the output as text and not as an image.

Answer (score 2):

The import from tkinter is replacing the import from PIL. Consider replacing

```
from tkinter import *
```

with

```
import tkinter as tk
```

and update the rest of your code with the new import.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
import PIL.Image
from tkinter import Tk

image2 = PIL.Image.open('hp png.png')
```

Hopefully it will work